# C++ Is there a way to have template overload based on type_traits?

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to have a function/class template overload based on type_traits information?

Example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Object>
class object_worker
{
public:
    object_worker(Object&& o) // o - is not POD
    {
        // do something
    }
};

template<typename Object>
class object_worker<std::is_pod<Object>::value == true> // how to make this thing work?
{
public:
    object_worker(Object &&o) // o - is POD
    {
        // do something different
    }
};
```

- Does it have to do something with a certain technique? like *partial template specialization*
- If this can be achieved, what is the name for it? (e.g. *partial template specialization*, *concepts*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like this. It's very widely used.

```
template<typename T, bool = is_pod<T>::value>>
class foo
{
};

// This is a partial template specialization.
// Triggered only when is_pod<T>::value is true
template<typename T>
class foo<T, true> // T can be only a POD type
{
};
```

Comment: Saved my day! Shouldn't it be rather called _full specialization_ for the second template parameter? I thought, _partial_ is something like: `template<typename T*> class cls{};`

Comment: Just hope nobody instantiates `foo<NonPod, true> x;` :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Aye, it's usually best to have a wrapper around this or maybe have it as a *detail* base class.

Comment: @KerrekSB fair enough :)

Comment: @andrgolubev No, a *full specialization* would look like` template<> class<int, true>` where *all* the templare parameters are specified. With the above, `T` still needs to be deduced.

Comment: @andrgolubev: An easy way to remember this: partial specializations are templates, full specializations are not.

Comment: @DeiDei good, didn't know that, thank you. By the way, by "wrapper" above you meant something like: `template<typename T> class wrapper : public foo<T, std::is_pod<T>>`?

@KerrekSB thanks!

Comment: @andrgolubev Yes, exactly. That way `wrapper<int, true>` will be impossible.